# Neo4j Cypher query of the Datamodel/Schema

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am searching for a cypher query that returns me the current data-model, meaning every node plus relationship, but only once.

I did find the query already in the past via stackoverflow.com or google, but I did not find it now again making a research.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is `CALL db.schema.visualization`

The output for the Movie Graph is:

[image]